# URL maiúsculas ou minúsculas

Tags: url, seo

Tratando-se de SEO faz alguma diferença o uso da URL do meu site ser toda minúscula?

Exemplo:

```
- http://localhost/produto/livro-stackoverflow
- http://localhost/Produto/Livro-StackOverflow
```

A minha dúvida é qual opção é recomendado a seguir e também o porque, se é um padrão ou se os motores de busca irão indexar melhor de tal forma.

Answer (score 1):

Nomes de domínios não são case sensitive porém as URLs sim. Então se por algum motivo você decidiu que suas URLs vão ser maiúsculas lembre-se que o usuário não está acostumado a digitar deste modo. Fique atento se você não tem links para uma mesma página com URLs em letras maiúsculas e minúsculas. O Google irá interpretar isso como páginas duplicadas.

Font: http://www.agenciamestre.com/seo/otimizacao-estrutura-urls/

Answer (score -1):

Não faz diferença alguma para o google ter letras maíusculas ou minúsculas. Para seguir o padrão utilize minúsculas no entanto se já tiver feito em maiúsculas não háverá problema algum.